# Align Issue - Navigation Bar CSS/html

Tags: html, css, browser, safari

I have an issue where my last link won't align properly. By this, I mean that in Chrome it works just fine but in Safari the last one is always put below in a weird way. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../Media/body-bg.png");
}


/* NOTE: Class */

.navigation-box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation-menu {
  margin: 6px 15px;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

.navigation-link {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation-link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right:50%;
  background:DarkGreen;
  transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
}

.selected::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background:DarkGreen;
}

.navigation-link:hover {
  color: Wheat;
}

.navigation-link:hover::before,.navigation-link.active:before {
  left: 0;
  right:0;
}

.vline {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Plans Du Bac</title>
    <link href="./Data/CSS/styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navigation-box">
      <h1 class="navigation-menu">
        <a href="#" class="navigation-link selected">Accueil</a><a class="vline"></a>
        <a href="./Data/Pages/cours.html" class="navigation-link">Cours</a><a class="vline"></a>
        <a href="./Data/Pages/plans.html" class="navigation-link">Plans</a><a class="vline"></a>
        <a href="./Data/Pages/plus.html" class="navigation-link">Plus</a>
      </h1>
    </div><br><br><br>
    <div class="text-box">
      <h1 class="page-title" style="width: 125px;">Accueil</h1>
        <p class="stylized">Plans du Bac est un fichier qui peut être utilisé sans internet, il regroupe les plans des oeuvres de français pour les objets d&apos;études de ES et de L ainsi que les principaux cours sur les objets d&apos;études ou sur les notions importantes.</p>
        <p class="stylized">Ce serait cool, si jamais vous voyez quelque chose qui ne marches pas sur le site ou si jamais vous voyez une erreur dans un cours ou dans une fiche de me le dire comme ça sa évitera que d&apos;autres personnes apprennent un mauvais cours ou des trucs faux. :)</p>
      <h1 class="a-box-title">Liste des modifications</h1>
        <p class="stylized"></p>
    <div>
  </body>

</html>
```

It will display well as a snippet, but as soon as you run it with Safari, it doesn't work anymore and the all thing is messed up (Here I added a border to make the box clearer, it won't be on the final version thought)

If anyone knows how to solve this it would be very much appreciated!

[image: The issue adressed]

Comment: Not sure why it would wrap in Safari, but if you remove the `content:""` from `::before` which is the same as removing `::before` it would align properly. It is positioned absolutely so I don't see why it would increase the width of the entire anchor. For now, you could add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.navigation-menu` until you figure out why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply `display:inline-block` to your anchor elements. `<a>` tags are by default inline ***but basically the defaults are browser-dependent*** so different browsers take it differently.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../Media/body-bg.png");
}


/* NOTE: Class */

.navigation-box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation-menu {
  margin: 6px 15px;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

.navigation-link {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation-link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background: DarkGreen;
  transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
}

.selected::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: DarkGreen;
}

.navigation-link:hover {
  color: Wheat;
}

.navigation-link:hover::before,
.navigation-link.active:before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.vline {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Plans Du Bac</title>
  <link href="./Data/CSS/styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navigation-box">
    <h1 class="navigation-menu">
      <a href="#" class="navigation-link selected">Accueil</a>
      <a class="vline"></a>
      <a href="./Data/Pages/cours.html" class="navigation-link">Cours</a>
      <a class="vline"></a>
      <a href="./Data/Pages/plans.html" class="navigation-link">Plans</a>
      <a class="vline"></a>
      <a href="./Data/Pages/plus.html" class="navigation-link">Plus</a>
    </h1>
  </div><br><br><br>
  <div class="text-box">
    <h1 class="page-title" style="width: 125px;">Accueil</h1>
    <p class="stylized">Plans du Bac est un fichier qui peut être utilisé sans internet, il regroupe les plans des oeuvres de français pour les objets d&apos;études de ES et de L ainsi que les principaux cours sur les objets d&apos;études ou sur les notions importantes.</p>
    <p class="stylized">Ce serait cool, si jamais vous voyez quelque chose qui ne marches pas sur le site ou si jamais vous voyez une erreur dans un cours ou dans une fiche de me le dire comme ça sa évitera que d&apos;autres personnes apprennent un mauvais cours ou des trucs
      faux. :)</p>
    <h1 class="a-box-title">Liste des modifications</h1>
    <p class="stylized"></p>
    <div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also adjust padding-bottom on the anchors to line up the bottom line